# Why does the size of a image in my floating element does not change?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently doing a tutorial on this [link](http://de.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson13.php).
The website is german but just look at the code and the picture above. 
I'd like to do something similar, with the `<div>` above the `<p>` but the size of my image is way larger so I try to make it smaller with `width`and `height` but it doesn't work. 
I can't figure out how to make it fit in that floating element.

Thank you in advance!!

html:

```
<body>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <div id="picture">
    <img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="photograph">
  </div>
  <p>sampletext</p>
</body>
```

css:

```
#picture {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: your current code please :)

Comment: I've added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the size for the container, but not for the image itself, so the image will display at its original size, and since the container doesn't have `overflow: hidden`, it will go out of the container.

Add this to fit the image into the container (well, `height` will depend on the image format):

EDIT: I changed `height`to 100% after the comment, wich distorts the image. If you set it to `auto`, and also set the container `height`to auto (or just erase it, since that is the default setting), it will become higher, according to its proportions/format. (The original image in this case is 400x400)

```css
#picture {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#picture img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <div id="picture">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="photograph" />
  </div>
  <p>sampletext</p>
</body>
```

Comment: That's kind of a solution for my problem. But as you said, it depends on the format of the image. I tried this out and also just with `height: 200px;`. Is there a way to shrink the image, so it's fully visible?

Comment: @Hip use it as background image

Comment: you can simply use `height: 100%`, but this will distort the image if it has a different format. I would just erase the `height` setting from the container, then the height will adjust to the image proportions.

Comment: @johannes When I try this I just get the same result. It's just the left side of the picture and the rest ist cut out.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've found the way to do it with background. Thanks dude!